# How to rename with keyword / specific text in terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, rename

I have a question, how do I just rename keywords? I have a very long file name. I am lazy to change it because I have to copy the name first.

example

```
filem87302839127921youtube90182mskldq7629121832.mp4
```

I usually rename files in a way

```
mv filem87302839127921youtube90182mskldq7629121832.mp4 video.mp4
```

but it was very troublesome

how can you do it with keywords?
for example like in

```
mv youtube video.mp4
```

so the system only takes keywords

help please

thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "keywords"? How could a keyword be used to identify a specific file? Why don't you use tab completion? Type filem87<tab> and the file name automatically will be completed.

Comment: You can even try glob completion mv \*youtube\* video.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try glob expansion

```
mv *youtube* video.mp4
```